# Android TableLayout not showing all 11 TableRows

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to create a layout for a simple version of the game MasterMind. I've set up a TableLayout with 10 TableRows with the same vertical weight to represent the pegs, and a final larger row at the bottom. Each of the main 10 rows consists of 4 Button elements (of equal weight) and two views on the sides so that the buttons stay centered. I have a layout already that I feel should work, but currently, only 9 of the rows will be displayed (the others exist, just off screen).

Can someone help me figure out why not all the elements are displaying? I'd do a series of LinearLayouts, but I've heard that is not very efficient, though I'm not certain my current method is either.

I'm hoping to get something along the lines of this:
[image: 11 rows]

but instead am getting this:
[image: Actual layout result]

Here is the layout (sorry it's long/repetitive):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b3b3b3"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <View
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: put it in scroll view..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encase the whole thing in:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">
   <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/game_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#b3b3b3"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    ...

</ScrollView>
```